# select dropdown and change google visulization chart's value in codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter

This is the timeline_chart.php file,when i select project in my drop down the value should be changed over here,please help me out!!
I have created show-hide div using jquery but its not working

```
<!--Div that will hold the pie chart-->
    <div id="chart_div" ></div>

    <!--Load the AJAX API-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

      // Load the Visualization API and the piechart package.
      google.load('visualization', '1.0', {'packages':['corechart']});

      // Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
      google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

      // Callback that creates and populates a data table, 
      // instantiates the pie chart, passes in the data and
      // draws it.

            google.load('visualization', '1', {'packages':['gauge']});
            google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

            function drawChart() {
        var time =<?php echo $time_count; ?>;
        var money = <?php echo $money_count; ?>;
        var hour = <?php echo $hour_count; ?>;
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Label', 'Value'],
          ['Time', time],
          ['Hours', money],
          ['Money', hour]
        ]);

        var options = {

          width: 300, height: 150,
          greenFrom: 0, greenTo: 100,max:200,min:0,redFrom:151,redTo:200,
          yellowFrom:101, yellowTo: 150,
          minorTicks: 5
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.Gauge(document.getElementById('chart_div'));

        chart.draw(data, options);


      }

    </script>
  </head>
```

Comment: but its not working !! Have you got any error??? Have you stuck in some line???

Comment: i am getting the value in pie chart,but on refresh,i want on change,and for that i have used jquery show-hide div